# pip install scipy, failed with error code -11

Tags: python, scipy, virtualenv

I was installing scipy for theano in virtualenv, it fails right after the start the installation. And it says it fails with error code -11. Could anyone can help me with this, what is the error code 11?

Here is the full trace of the error, from the beginning of when I run the command:

```
(dl)[haohan@sirius deeplearning]$ pip install theano
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): theano in ./dl/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy>=1.5.0 in ./dl/lib/python2.7/site-   packages (from theano)
Downloading/unpacking scipy>=0.7.2 (from theano)
Downloading scipy-0.14.0.tar.gz (10.2MB): 10.2MB downloaded
Running setup.py (path:/home/haohan/deeplearning/dl/build/scipy/setup.py) egg_info for package scipy

    warning: no previously-included files matching '*_subr_*.f' found under directory 'scipy/linalg/src/id_dist/src'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'scipy/special/tests/data/boost'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'scipy/special/tests/data/gsl'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/build'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/source/generated'
    no previously-included directories found matching '*/__pycache__'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*~' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.bak' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.swp' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found anywhere in distribution
Installing collected packages: scipy
    Running setup.py install for scipy
Cleaning up...
Command /home/haohan/deeplearning/dl/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/home/haohan/deeplearning/dl/build/scipy/setup.py';
exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" 
install --record /tmp/pip-svx8Wr-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 
/home/haohan/deeplearning/dl/include/site/python2.7 failed with error code -11 in /home/haohan/deeplearning/dl/build/scipy
Storing debug log for failure in /home/haohan/.pip/pip.log
```

I break the second last line into several lines, for the convenience of reading.
I think this is very strange that the error occurs barely after the installation starts and I have just use pip to install numpy successfully, so it's unlikely to be the problem of pip. Then, where is the problem? How should I fix it?

Could it be related with the system? But I guess I cannot print the system information out since I don't have sudo permission...

Could it because that our cluster is too old? That's the only explanation that I can think of.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What does `/home/haohan/.pip/pip.log` show?

Comment: @JohnZwinck thanks. It shows exactly what has been showed in this post, nothing more...

Comment: I'm having the same error code thrown at me. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34595603/1391441

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried updating setuptools?

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

Then try installing theano again.

When I encountered this problem while developing my own package, the root cause was with imports in `setup.py`. I changed what `setup.py` imported and then it worked. Maybe `theano`'s setup is importing a package which has an incompatible version?

If the problem isn't solved by updating packages or editing imports in setup, you can try to debug by using the `vvv` flag to get more information, as in `pip install -vvv theano`.

As for the error code you're seeing:

> A negative value -N indicates that the child was terminated by signal
>   N (Unix only)

https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.returncode

Code 11 means segfault in *nix, although `os.strerror(11)` reports "Resource temporarily unavailable". Since I get segfaults when I attempt python setup.py egg_info, I'm betting it's the first (segfault) definition of 11 that's relevant.

If your segfault dumped a core, it's probably in `/var/lib/systemd/coredump/` if you're using systemd.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/349433/183163
If you can't find a core, check `ulimit -c`. If it reports `0`, run `ulimit -c unlimited` to enable core dumping. You can get the full path to the most recent dump file by `ls -rtd /var/lib/systemd/coredump/* | tail -1`

To read the dump, you can use `gdb`. For example:

```
gdb python /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.python.6146.f06ba728dae74cfbbaf80acb8d392dd5.4477.1524677641000000.lz4
```